# Split JSON file into multiple files using Python(notebook)

Tags: python, json, split

I am using Python (notebook)
I have a JSON file with this structure store in json_out var:

```
[
{"any": 2023},
{
"dia": 24,
"mes": 1,
"any": 2023,
"mes_referencia": 12,
"any_referencia": 2022,
"calendari_nom": "CCC"
},
{
"dia": 4,
"mes": 12,
"any": 2023,
"mes_referencia": 10,
"any_referencia": 2023,
"calendari_nom": "FFF"
},
{
"dia": 4,
"mes": 1,
"any": 2023,
"mes_referencia": 0,
"any_referencia": 2022,
"calendari_nom": "GAS",
"periode_ref": "TT"
},
{
"dia": 3,
"mes": 10,
"any": 2023,
"mes_referencia": 0,
"any_referencia": 2023,
"calendari_nom": "GAS",
"periode_ref": "22"
}
]
```

I need to split the file into multiple files, each for each { } block. I am a little confused on how to do this. I have tried this but it doesn't work to me:

```
import json

with (json_out, 'r') as f_in:
    data = json.load(f_in)

    for i, fact in enumerate(data[], 1):

        with open('data_out_{}.json'.format(i), 'w') as f_out:
            d = {}
            json.dump(d, f_out, indent=4)
```

Can you give any idea on how to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide details as to what "doesn't work to me" means?

Comment: `enumerate(data[], 1)` should be `enumerate(data, 1)` (without brackets).

Comment: Yes, I am getting the message:                                                         
  Cell In[35], line 6
    for i, fact in enumerate(data[], 1):
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax. Perhaps you forgot a comma?.  The problem is that I have not put anything in the brakes data[ ]. But I am not sure what to put because the format os my JSONi file.

Comment: Ups, I just see that Yevhen answered.  I have tried and I get this message:                                                                                                                
          1 import json
----> 3 with (json_output, 'r') as f_in:
      4     data = json.load(f_in)
      6     for i, fact in enumerate(data, 1):

TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support the context manager protocol.        I think the problem is the 'r'  because my I am getting my JSON from a variable

Comment: What is *json_out*? Is it a filename or a list or something else?

Comment: Previously I have converted a csv file into a JSON format, I have storaged it in a val **json_out**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example how you can create the files from the provided Json file:

```py
import json

with open("data.json", "r") as f_in:
    data = json.load(f_in)

    for i, d in enumerate(data, 1):
        with open(f"data_out_{i}.json", "w") as f_out:
            json.dump(d, f_out, indent=4)
```

For example `data_out_2.json` will contain:

```json
{
    "dia": 24,
    "mes": 1,
    "any": 2023,
    "mes_referencia": 12,
    "any_referencia": 2022,
    "calendari_nom": "CCC"
}
```

---

EDIT: If `json_output` contains string with JSON encoded data:

```py
import json

json_output = """\
[
{"any": 2023},
{
"dia": 24,
"mes": 1,
"any": 2023,
"mes_referencia": 12,
"any_referencia": 2022,
"calendari_nom": "CCC"
},
{
"dia": 4,
"mes": 12,
"any": 2023,
"mes_referencia": 10,
"any_referencia": 2023,
"calendari_nom": "FFF"
},
{
"dia": 4,
"mes": 1,
"any": 2023,
"mes_referencia": 0,
"any_referencia": 2022,
"calendari_nom": "GAS",
"periode_ref": "TT"
},
{
"dia": 3,
"mes": 10,
"any": 2023,
"mes_referencia": 0,
"any_referencia": 2023,
"calendari_nom": "GAS",
"periode_ref": "22"
}
]"""

data = json.loads(json_output)

for i, d in enumerate(data, 1):
    with open(f"data_out_{i}.json", "w") as f_out:
        json.dump(d, f_out, indent=4)
```

Comment: Thanks Andrej, I have already tried because I saw a past post from you.  My problem in this point is that my JSON is not in a file, is in a val json_out,  because I have previously converted from a csv.  So I am not sure what to write instead of  open("data.json", "r").     If I write on the first part:  **with json_output as f_in:** .  It says:  **'str' object does not support the context manager protocol**.  Any ideas

Comment: @JoseMariaAcevedoReinoso If the variable `data` already contains list of dictionaries, then skip the fist `open()` and enumerate over it directly. If it contains just string, then do `data = json.loads(data)`

Comment: @AndrejKesely  I have do this:                                                     import json
`with json_output as f_in:
    data = json.load(f_in)
    print(data)
    for i, d in enumerate(data, 1):
        with open(f"data_out_{i}.json", "w") as f_out:
            json.dump(d, f_out, indent=4)`       It gives me the message **TypeError: 'str' object does not support the context manager protocol**.                                                                                             I also have realised that the JSON that I create doesn't have identation.  Could it be a problem?

Comment: I think I will write in another answer (this question) to make it more clear.

Comment: @JoseMariaAcevedoReinoso I've updated my answer.